# R SHiny - The difference between inline css and custom css

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

Apologies if this question has been asked and answered elsewhere (I have searched for it but couldn't find a solution). Warning, I have zero to little HTML experience.

I have been developing a shiny app, which has required a fair bit of tinkering with some of the shiny widgets using css.

Essentially, I am confused as to the difference between doing this inline using "style = ":

```
column(width = 12, style = "margin-top: 25px", ... )
```

And using tags:

```
tags$style(HTML("{margin-top: 25px;}"))
```

For me, the inline looks cleaner and makes more sense, and in the majority of my use cases has been working. Although I have it appears that in general people recommend the tags$style approach - what is the reason for this?

I imagine there are some good resources online that I could learn more about css that will help with my shiny skills, I would love some suggestions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is basically that `tags$style` is a "global" styling, while in the first case you are styling only what is inside the column (which is a `div` element).

It is recommended to use style because you can give global styling definitions, instead of manually adjusting all the elements you create. If you are still willing to learn css, then you will quickly understand this point.

I would say as well that the best practice for small apps is to create a separate style.css document where you define the defaults for your app. Then save inline styling for special cases in which you want to use exceptions to the default (inline "generally" takes precedence over the rest).

There are plenty of online resources for learning css. The very basic is covered well in my opinion in https://www.w3schools.com/css/. Besides, shiny uses `bootstrap`, which may be interesting to learn in this context.